# Lucas' Theorem and Pascal's Triangle

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics, soft-question, binomial-coefficients

I have a general question about Lucas' Theorem. Lucas' Theorem says the following:

> **Theorem (Lucas' Theorem)** Let $p$ be a prime number. Write $n$ and $k$ in base $p$: $n = a_0 + a_{1}+a_{2}p^{2} + \cdots + a_{d}p^{d}$ and $k = b_0+b_{1}p+b_{2}p^{2}+ \cdots +b_{d}p^{d}$ where $0 \leq a_i,b_i \leq p-1$. Then $$ \ \binom{n}{k} \equiv \prod_{i=0}^{d} \binom{a_i}{b_i} \pmod{p}$$

Another way of viewing this is that in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $\binom{n}{k}$ is a product of binomial coefficients.

> **Question**. How does this theorem correspond to the geometric interpretation of Pascal's Triangle? Namely, for any entry in Pascal's triangle which is odd mark a $\text{x}$. Else leave it blank. So we basically get a fractal like structure. Is Lucas' Theorem just a statement of a way to get extra rows of Pascal's Triangle given that we know $2^n$ rows?

Comment: Where is $2^n$ coming from ?

Comment: $2^n$ is the total number of subsets of an $n$-element set.

Answer (score 2):

When $p = 2$, Lucas' Theorem states that ${n \choose m} \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$ if and only if in the binary expansion of $n = (\overline{ \cdots n_1n_0})_2$ and $m = (\overline{ \cdots m_1m_0})_2$, some binary digit (say the $d$th binary digit) satisfies $n_d = 0, m_d = 1$. In particular, this shows that ${2^k + n \choose m} \equiv {2^k + n \choose 2^k + m} \equiv {n \choose m} \pmod{2}$ when $2^k > n > m$, which describes the recursive nature of the [Sierpinski triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) that can be found in Pascal's triangle by highlighting the odd elements (which it seems is the geometric interpretation you referred to). However, this is a fairly restricted application of Lucas' Theorem and can be seen by easier means.